# apply shadow for header <h3> tag using jquery

Tags: jquery, plugins, shadow

Is it possible to apply shadow for header `<h3>` tags jquery....

[alt text http://img541.imageshack.us/img541/9603/57972600.jpg](http://img541.imageshack.us/img541/9603/57972600.jpg)

Here home,Manage users,Enquiry and reports are headers and i would like to add shadow to it...
I looked for jquery shadow plugin which has div samples but how to apply the same for header tags?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
       $("#exampleDiv").shadow({
           width:5, 
           startOpacity:60, 
           endOpacity:10, 
           cornerHeight:8, 
           color:"#000000"
       });
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does this won't work?

```
$(function(){
   $("h3").shadow({
       width:5, 
       startOpacity:60, 
       endOpacity:10, 
       cornerHeight:8, 
       color:"#000000"
   });
})
```

Comment: it works but it breaks my accordion (ie) home tab seems to get shorter and other tabs seems to get squeezed to lesser width..

Comment: yes!... because your h3 are now wrap with div or some sort... I can't think of a way around it... `.shadow()` breaks your dom... that's why accordion is not working as expected...

Comment: The CSS3 shadow attribute works in most modern browsers, and it's a lot simpler to use. Nowadays, I'd just go with that...